# Scala return type when extending collection

Tags: scala, polymorphism, scala-collections

If I write

> class Things extends scala.collection.immutable.HashSet[Int]
>
> new Things + 5

Then the result is

> res0: scala.collection.immutable.HashSet[Int] = Set(5)

What do I need to do for the result to be of type **Things**?  I suspect the answer might be [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259297/extending-a-scala-collection), but am struggling to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't really tell without a sample of your code but you can take a look at Jesse Eichar's post which provides a walk through the implementation of a custom collection and addresses your question nicely.

http://daily-scala.blogspot.com/2010/04/creating-custom-traversable.html

Comment: Spot on.  BTW, the code given in the question should work stand alone in the REPL.

Comment: Re: code. Sorry, yes you did. Somehow I was expecting more code and missed that.